# Single words for "lesser or equal" and "greater or equal"

Tags: single-word-requests

The opposite of "lesser" is "greater or equal" and vice versa. Does the English language have single word antonyms for "lesser" and "greater"?

Comment: Lesser and greater are antonyms of each other, are you asking for synonyms of those two words?

Comment: I think you're confusing quantifier usage: **9 is greater than 6; 4 is less than 8; y is greater than or equal to x** with adjectival usage (**Lesser Antilles; Greater Manchester**) and use-of-adjective-as-noun (**the lesser of two evils**).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - You're correct. I'm asking for the quantifier usage of "lesser" and "greater", not the adjective or adjective-as-a-noun usage. That's what I'm looking for, and that's pretty clear to me. =)

Comment: Yes, there is one. "within" is the best single word for <=, but I can't find a word for >= so far.

Comment: <= at most / within, >= at least, < below / smaller, > above / bigger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no single word antonym for lesser' to capture 'greater than or equal' (likewise for 'greater')

However a common shorter way to say the opposite of 'lesser' is to say

> no lesser

For example 'There are no less people in my group than yours' means my group may have exactly the same number or maybe more.

It is exactly the meaning you're looking for, but is not a single word, and also puts a large 'negation' burden on the reader/listener.

Comment: Use "fewer" for things you can count and "less" for things you can't. The same goes for "many" & "much," respectively. For example, you might say that "Joe has fewer children & less money than John."

Answer (score 5):

I believe your initial premise - The opposite of "lesser" is "greater or equal"- is a little incorrect and is causing some confusion.  Qualities can be dissimilar without necessarily being opposites (which implies a certain complementary antagonism).

For example, even though things that are red aren't green, red wouldn't be considered the opposite of green.   Similarly, one thing can be equal to another (which means it's not greater than the other), but that doesn't necessarily mean it's the opposite of being greater than the other.

I believe the antonyms for "lesser" and "greater" would respectively be "greater" and "lesser."

Comment: True, but I want the quantitative antonyms of "lesser" and "greater" - if they exist.

Comment: I think in that case, "not greater" and "not lesser" is probably the most concise wording.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question accurately, then I believe that the answer is No, there is no single word that means "Greater or equal".  You can use the symbol ≥ , but that symbol is called the "greater-or-equal sign", not anything shorter.

Answer (score 2):

"Opposite of" is a relation that is meaningful **only** in a one-dimensional semantic cline with a center point, like *tepid* in the following:

- *freezing - cold - cool - **tepid** - warm - hot - boiling*

In this cline, *freezing* is the opposite of *boiling*, *cold* of *hot*, and *cool* of *warm*; but there's no opposite for *tepid* because it's a zero point, distinguishing negative from positive values. Very neat.

However, almost all semantic frames require more than one dimension. Comparing quantities is a good example of a multi-dimensional frame -- *lesser* and *greater* both presuppose at least two separate quantitative measures, and a comparison operation ranking them. This is much too ambitious to support a simple concept like "opposite".

For another example, what's the "opposite of" *He may do it*?

- *He may not do it.*
- *He won't do it.*
- *He can't do it.*
- *He must do it.*

or maybe something else? There are [a number of dimensions involved with modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html).

And we're not even talking about metaphorical uses, like *the lesser of two evils*.